# Echo a result from function php

Tags: php, function

I use the following functions in my PHP script:

```
function draw_dealer_card() {
//get a key
$key = array_rand($_SESSION["dealer_pile"]);
// add the card to the hand
$_SESSION["dealer_hand"][] = $_SESSION["dealer_pile"][$key];
echo $_SESSION["dealer_pile"][$key];
}
```

and this one:

```
function list_dealer_hand() {

}
```

`draw_dealer_card()` grabs a random card from the array and places it in the hand of the dealer. And the echo shows the cards the dealer has drawn.

And the `list_dealer_hand()` is empty for now.

And that is my problem, the `list_dealer_hand()` needs to contain the echo from `draw_dealer_card()`.

And i can't really find a way to switch them around.

I hope i provided you guys with enough information otherwise please let me know!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not understood quietly but use return statement (`return $_SESSION["dealer_pile"][$key];`).

Comment: as AVD mentioned use a return value inside the functions. and echo function();
this way as randomizer mentioned u can reinsert values into other functions.

Comment: @AVD Thanks for your asnswer, but it seems to give me another random value. So 1 random value in the draw and anothe random one in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it as a variable:

```
list_dealer_hand($value){
   echo $value;
}
```

Or store it in a session variable works too..

Answer (score 0):

The function `draw_dealer_card()` could return the value instead of echo the value:

```
function draw_dealer_card() {
    //get a key
    $key = array_rand($_SESSION["dealer_pile"]);
    // add the card to the hand
    $_SESSION["dealer_hand"][] = $_SESSION["dealer_pile"][$key];
    return $_SESSION["dealer_pile"][$key];
}

function list_dealer_hand() {
   $return_value_of_draw_dealer_card = draw_dealer_card();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i've tried this myself too, it doesn't show anything.

Comment: Is it show the value if you use your "echo"-method?

Comment: Sorry, i misspelled something, yeah it's showing me things. But not the right things. It gives me random values in both fields. So a random value in draw_dealer_card and inside the list_dealer_hand

Comment: Well, list_dealer_hand() calls the function draw_dealer_card() which returns a random value back. If you echo $return_value_of_draw_dealer_card it should be the same value as if you echo the value in draw_dealer_card() directly.

Comment: Yeah, i understand the logic, this is what i tried at first too. But since this doesn't seem to work. I tried to ask my question here, but it seems this should be the solution.. even tho it doesn't seem to be working for me.